# Trouble with react-countup and easingfn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I'm trying to make a countuptimer (up to 2022) in React using react-countup library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countup

I can't get the timer to do a simple ease-in at the last few numbers. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import CountUp from "react-countup";

function TimelineCounter() {
    const easingFn = (t, b, c, d) => {
        const ts = (t /= d) * t;
        const tc = ts * t;
        return b + c * (tc + -3 * ts + 3 * t);
      };

  return (
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <div class="text-9xl">
        <CountUp start={2003} end={2022} duration="5" easingFn={easingFn} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TimelineCounter;
```

Answer (score 0):

`easingFn` is a function that specifies the rate of change over time. You can check possible function implementations on this page https://easings.net/.
What you probably want to implement is a cubic or quint (more aggressive ramp up) functions. Here are a few examples:

- ease out cubic `(t, b, c, d) => c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;`
- ease out quint `(t, b, c, d) => c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t*t + 1) + b;`

Answer (score 0):

For a simple ease effect, you don't need to create *easingFn*, just set the *useEasing* prop to true like the following code

```
<CountUp start={2003} end={2022} duration={5} useEasing={true} />
```

**Note**

- In the github documentation, *useEasing* default value is true, but in my installed version 6.4.1 it's not as the documentation, so you should specify the prop to be true yourself.